# Gradle never resolves Artifactory before JCenter repository for dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, artifactory, jcenter

I have a Gradle build script for a Java project. I have set up an internal Artifactory repository as a remote for the project's dependencies.

*When the project is compiling, I want Gradle to first go to Artifactory and request; if it fails there, it should next try JCenter as a backup.*

I am using the Gradle Artifactory plugin, v3.1.1, in Gradle 2.8. The plugin defines its `contextUrl`, `publish` repo, and `resolve` repo in a closure:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactoryContextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'Release'
            username = "${artifactoryUser}"
            password = "${artifactoryPassword}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'repo'
            username = "${artifactoryUser}"
            password = "${artifactoryPassword}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}
```

Both the buildscript and the project define their repositories:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'Artifactory'
            url "${artifactoryContextUrl}repo"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactoryUser}"
                password = "${artifactoryPassword}"
            }
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        name 'Artifactory'
        url "${artifactoryContextUrl}repo"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactoryUser}"
            password = "${artifactoryPassword}"
        }
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

I have had to resort to these duplicate statements that repeatedly define the Artifactory repo, as I can't seem to find a way to define and place the `artifactory` closure in the build script so that Gradle refers to this defined `resolve` repo before trying JCenter.

Preferably, the solution would address this duplicate definition in both the `buildscript` and `repositories` closures, but it's seems unlikely that I could refer to the properties inside the `artifactory` closure before the Gradle-Artifactory plugin is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't need both `artifactory {}` config and `repositories` config in the main part of your script. use `repositories` to point to your Artifactory instance in the `buildscript` and then `artifactory{}` DSL in the main part.
2. You don't need to configure `jcenter` in your script, Artifactory proxies it by default. You don't need to "back up" Artifactory with JCenter, because whatever exists in JCenter will always be resolvable from Artifactory.

Comment: 1. I will test that out. Thanks.
2. The idea w/ the jcenter backup reference is that Artifactory is running behind our firewall. Having jcenter referenced as a backup is there in case our Artifactory server is unavailable. In that case, Gradle would get no response from attempting to resolve Artifactory, and try JCenter next. With the jcenter reference in Gradle, however, it seems to always resolve dependencies through JCenter first, then Artifactory if unavailable in JCenter (which is the case for our own libraries). We want to reverse that order, to try Artifactory first, then JCenter.

Comment: Shortcutting Artifactory is a really bad idea. If you are worried about Artifactory being up, you should explore Active-Active and/or Active-Passive deployments of Artifactory instead of shortcutting it in case it's down.

Comment: thanks for that deployment information. HA for our Artifactory is the better solution than some Gradle workaround.

Comment: Absolutely! That's the way to go.

Comment: I have the opposite problem! Artifactory is always resolved before center in my build. How do I reverse the order? We have an internal Artifactory where our libs are deployed but it doesn't correctly proxy center so I need to do the inverse.

Comment: Why it doesn't correctly proxy jcenter? That's what need to be fixed. You should always resolve from Arifactory.

Comment: The reasons why are unknown. We are currently do not pull from Artifactory but I am making changes to slowly phase it in. The first milestone would be to pull only our internal dependencies from Artifactory. Subsequent milestones would address the proxying. Again, is there any way to reverse the order of resolution? Or is this one of those things where order should be insignificant?

Comment: Are you using the Gradle Artifactory plugin, or use the `repositories` closure for that?

Comment: regarding 1) `repositories { Artifactory {} }` ? I can't find that any name is automatically exosed as reusable repository name from documentation https://docs.gradle.org/5.3/userguide/declaring_repositories.html